# Navigating a Dictionary of Arrays of Dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I've been struggling with this for over a month, so I have tried to solve this on my own.

I have a plist of lists that contain dictionaries of items. How do I drill down to, for example, display the checked status of the items in the shopping list?

```
<dict>
<key>Shopping List</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Green Tea</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Tempeh</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Kimuchi</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Jasmine Rice</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>To-Do List</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Wash Car</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Run Diswasher</string>
        <key>Checked</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code you have so far related to accessing the data in this plist. Then someone can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// First we get the path for the plist
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"]; // Replace PlistFileName with your plist name (without its file extension)

// Then, we get the first dictionary (containing "Shopping List" and "To-Do List") 
NSDictionary *listsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

// Then, we get the array contained in the "Shopping List" object of the previous dictionary we got
NSArray *theShoppingList = [listsDictionary objectForKey:@"Shopping List"];

// Then, we get the dictionary representing an item of the list at a given index in the previous array we got
NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[theShoppingList objectAtIndex:index]; // index represents the index of the item in the plist

// Last but not least, we get the Checked value (as a boolean value) contained in the item
Boolean checked = [[item objectForKey:@"Checked"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the (commented) answer, I really appreciate it. One question, if I didn't know in advance the "given index" how can I fast enumerate through the listsDictionary to grab the index?

Comment: You mean enumerating "theShoppingList" array, no ? Enumerating a dictionary does not guarantee sorting...

Comment: You've just highlighted how much I still have to learn. And yes, I have noticed that dictionaries don't guarantee sorting. To rephrase my question: if I didn't know in advance the "given index" how would I get the index of the item in the plist

Comment: It depends on how you want to determine it, you can enumerate through "theShoppingList" with a "for in" statement like that, it would permit you to determine which item you want but may not be the fastest solution (I'm still learning too, so I cannot give you a better solution to this problem... ) : `for (NSDictionary *item in theShoppingList) {   
NSString *name = [[item objectForKey:@"Name"] stringValue]; // Check if this is the item you want ?   
        }`

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file into NSDictionary, you will have a tree structure like this,

```
@{ 
  @"Shopping List" :
   @[
     @{
        @"Name": @"Green Tea",
        @"Checked": [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
    },
    @{
        @"Name": @"Tempeh", 
        @"Checked": [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
    },
    @{
        @"Name": @"Jasmine Rice", 
        @"Checked": [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
    },
  ],

  @"To-Do List":
  @[
    @{
        @"Name": @"Wash Car", 
        @"Checked": [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
    },
    @{
        @"Name": @"Run Diswasher", 
        @"Checked": [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]
    },
  ]
}
```

I have created the dictionary from the above plist using new Objective C dictionary literal. This should make more sense and could be easy to parse things.

So, to display if "Green Tea" is checked you would do,

```
dict[@"Shopping List"][0][@"Checked"]
```

For Jasmine rice,

```
dict[@"Shopping List"][2][@"Checked"]
```

Wash car,

```
dict[@"To-Do list"][0][@"Checked"]
```

I created a small helper function with which you can enumerate all the keys and choose specific value for some key,

```
- (void)enumerateDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{
  for(NSString *key in dictionary){
    id object = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
      for(id dict in object)
        [self enumerateDictionary:dict];
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        [self enumerateDictionary:object];
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        NSLog(@"Name => %@\nChecked => %@\n", dictionary[@"Name"], dictionary[@"Checked"]);
  }
}
```

When you read the dictionary just pass the dictionary to this function, and it will show all the values and corresponding checked value. You could then add some codes to choose specific ones.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps too. To both of you: Sorry I can't up vote your answers.

Comment: What do you mean, why can't you upvote the answer. What is your question actually ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: Vote up requires a reputation of 15. This is my first post

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :). I have been through all of these.